# jQuery, escape characters when selecting by href

Tags: javascript, jquery, escaping

I'm trying to select an element based on its href within a table of records.  I have two links for each record:

'reorder=+' and 'reorder=-'

If I use

```
a[href*=reorder]
```

both elements are recognised successfully, however if I try to differentiate between the two, nothing happens eg:

```
a[href*=reorder\=\+]
```

Is there a way around this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this?  The quotes may make a difference.

```
$("a[href*='reorder=+']")
```

Comment: Apologies, my mistake.  The actual href values were reorder=-(id) or just reorder=(id).

Is there a way to filter based on the absence of a character?

Thanks.

Comment: This shows you how to create a custom filter.  You can use it, or just take the principles and use them in a .each(function() { ... }).  http://www.west-wind.com/Weblog/posts/519980.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$('a[href="reorder=+"]');
```

Comment: Why don't you add the HTML to your question, so we can see more information, then?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('a').filter(function()
{
    return $(this).attr("href").IndexOf("reorder=+")!=-1;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Dan, Given your comment

> Apologies, my mistake. The actual href values were reorder=-(id) or just reorder=(id). Is there a way to filter based on the absence of a character?

the selector you need to use is:

```
$("a[href*='reorder=']:not([href*='reorder=-'])")
```

This selects all anchors where the href contains "reorder=" and then removes all those which contain "reorder=-", thus leaving those which are of the form "reorder=(id)".